# How to calculate a single cross correlation coefficient of matrices A with other matrices B python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have three matrices A B and C. I want to find which matrice (B & C) have the best cross-correlation coefficient with the matrices A.

```
A=np.array([[1, 2, 4],[3, 4, 5],[1, 4, 5]])  
B=np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 4],[1, 4, 5]])   
C=np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1],[1, 4, 5]])
```

scipy.correlate2d and numpy.corrcoef are giving matrice as output. I just need single correlation coefficient value so that I can find the more similar matrices to A.
Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24983), you can vectorize the input matrices, and calculate the correlation coefficient from the vector data:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5]])
B = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 4, 5]])
C = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 5]])
CC_AB = np.corrcoef(A.ravel(), B.ravel())
CC_AC = np.corrcoef(A.ravel(), C.ravel())
print('Correlation between A and B:', CC_AB[0, 1])
print('Correlation between A and C:', CC_AC[0, 1])
```

As you can see, the output of `np.corrcoef()` is a 2 x 2 symmetric matrix with ones on its diagonal (autocorrelation). The correlation coefficient you are interested in is off-diagonal. In your case, the results are:

```
Correlation between A and B: 0.7576538541439333
Correlation between A and C: 0.5141222581690976
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the max and argmax of the output:

```
corr=scipy.correlate2d(A,B)
maxCorr=corr.max()
indexmaxCorr=np.argmax(corr)
```

this is due because correlate is basically a convolution and then you have similarity value for different "shifting".

Comment: My matrice is actually 2048 x 2048. so its taking long time to compute. The center pixel will give the correlation without shift. But I am wasting so much time computation resource. Can I get correlation coefficient without shiftting.

Comment: so you should not do a cross-correlation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation . just a measure of similarity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure .
there is many different way to do that. I guess the most basic/used one is the mean squared error 
if you have scikit installed you can do:
`from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse = mean_squared_error(A, B)`
you have other metrics implemented in sklearn.metrics.
the mse can be coded using just numpy as well `np.square(np.subtract(A, B)).mean()`

Comment: I am having matrice from a image file..so I cannot use mean_squared_error(A, B) or similarity I am sorry..Still I will try

Comment: i don't get what it changes that matrix are coming from image file. you can always vectorize a matrix if necessary. lot of similarity measurements are used on image...

Comment: you can have a look here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Comment: you have corrcoeff solution as @Leonard said. mutual information https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/mutual_information.html